# How does Amiibo and 3DS work?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, amiibo

I really like Amiibo and I'm getting the new 3DS this month. So I would like to know how Amiibo will work with the 3DS and if there are already games anounced which will support them.

Comment: I am guessing that SSB4 will work, and maybe a new Mario Cart game (maybe), but I do not know much about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiibo#Supported_games):

> Supported games offer one of two kinds of Amiibo compatibility; the ability to access an Amiibo figure's NFC tag and store data, and read-only recognition. Each Amiibo figurine largely corresponds to a specific game that can access its storage space, though some may have multiple games that can use it. However, each Amiibo figurine can only store data from one compatible game at a time, meaning data must be deleted from the figure in order to use it with a different title.

These 3DS games are:

- Super Smash Bros. for Nintendo 3DS
- Ace Combat: Assault Horizon Legacy Plus
- One Piece: Super Grand Battle! X
- Code Name: S.T.E.A.M.

Here's the [compatibility list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiibo#List_of_Amiibo_figures) for each Amiibo.

**Important note**:
Amiibo figurines can be used *directly* with the Wii U GamePad and New Nintendo 3DS series, but you need an *adapter* for the rest of the Nintendo 3DS series to be released in 2015.

---

To connect an Amiibo to the Wii U, you'll need to place the Amiibo on the rectangular icon on the lower left corner of the gamepad:

[image]

For the New 3DS, you only need to place the Amiibo on the touchscreen:

[image]

Comment: You should mention the difference in how you connect an amiibo to the current 3DS systems and the new 3ds systems.

Comment: @kenjara I've edited my answer.